# Script Component in SSIS Implementation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a code which is implemented in C# and When I try to Implement the same in SSIS component it is giving me error It would be of great help if any one could help me in this conversion.

Code is

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> thenames = new List<string>(new string[]
        {
            "XY YZ ZX Jr",
            "XY, Jr TR YZ",
            "XY Sr YZ.",
            "XY YZ Sr",
            "XY I YZ",
            "XY I YZ",
            "XY II, YZ",
            "XY YZ II",
            "XY YZ III.",
            "XY III. Yz."
        });

        var reg = new Regex(@"\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var titles = new Regex(@"[JS]r|II?I?");

        foreach (String str in thenames)
        {
            var names = reg.Matches(str)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();

            names.Reverse();
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            foreach (String name in names)
            {
                Match title = titles.Match(name);
                if (title.Success)
                {
                    output.Insert(0, name);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.Add(name);
                }
            }
            output.Reverse();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", output.ToArray()));

        }
    }
}
```

This code provides the below result

```
XY, YZ, ZX, Jr
XY, TR, YZ, Jr
XY, YZ, Sr
XY, YZ, Sr
XY, YZ, I
XY, YZ, I
XY, YZ, II
XY, YZ, II
XY, YZ, III
XY, Yz, III
```

I need to send the input from a table and get the required result. But not from the input so I tried writing in Script component of SSIS and below is the code and error I am Facing

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

        public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        var reg = new Regex(@"\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var titles = new Regex(@"[JS]r|II?I?");

        foreach (String str in Row.XYZ)
        {
            var names = reg.Matches(str)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();

            names.Reverse();
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            foreach (String name in names)
            {
                Match title = titles.Match(name);
                if (title.Success)
                {
                    output.Insert(0, name);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.Add(name);
                }
            }
            output.Reverse();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", output.ToArray()) + ".");

        }

    }

}
```

Error:

```
Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'
```

Comment: What data type is the XYZ column?

Comment: @KyleHale nvarchar(50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific error is you are doing a foreach command against a string variable (Row.XYZ), where each iterated item returned is a *char* type and so you when you try to re-cast it as a *String* in the loop initializer you get the error you see.

Your more general problem is that your script task already is part of a loop. In your original code, you read in a *List* of *Strings* and so had to loop through them, but in SSIS, the loop is the data flow itself, and so each row is already passed into **Input0_ProcessInputRow**  individually and so you don't need to do a foreach (Row.XYZ). Instead just do this:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var titles = new Regex(@"[JS]r|II?I?");


            var names = reg.Matches(Row.XYZ)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();

            names.Reverse();
            List<string> output = new List<string>();
            foreach (String name in names)
            {
                Match title = titles.Match(name);
                if (title.Success)
                {
                    output.Insert(0, name);
                }
                else
                {
                    output.Add(name);
                }
            }
            output.Reverse();
           Row.YUX = string.Join(", ", output.ToArray()) + ".");
```

Comment: Thank you so much @KyleHale I have one small doubt what would be my output column name be?

Comment: how should I redirect cleaned data to go to a column named YUX?

Comment: In your Script Transformation Editor window, select the "Inputs and Outputs" tab and add your YUX column as a new Output column to Output 0. Then you can set the value of YUX in your code: Row.YUX = value;

Comment: can you please edit your code once? so that it redirects the result to YUX

Comment: Sure, last line changed.